# Link that sends a value but doesn't refresh the page and opens in a div

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Ok so the goal im trying to accomplish here is a i have a list of information from a mysql table on a page in a div called content. i want to have the values to be hyperlinks that use jquery to open the content without refreshing the page. The value I want to send is a customer ID number that when its sent to the page can run some sql to bring up a custeomers information.

So lets say the customer is John Smith and his Customer id number is 20.

```
<a href="" id="$row['customer_id']">Smith, John</a>
```

my jquery that i have been using on other links is as follows.

```
$("#WhateverTheCustomerIDis").click(function(){
   $("#container").load("company/view-customer.php");
})
```

then in my sql i wanna do like a "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'the value sent by link'"

Can anyone help me figure out how to set up the jquery and the links to work so when the link gets clicked it opens the view customer page in the div without refreshing the page.

Comment: `.load('company/view-customer.php?name=' + this.text())`?

Comment: not possible as he is selecting an un-defined index, You can't select an element without its Id or with a dynamic id unless you grab it other way first then get its id.

Comment: notice that in html ids should not start with a number. Prefix your id attribute with some string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="" id="$row['customer_id']" class="userLink">Smith, John</a>

$(".userLink").click(function(){
   $("#container").load("company/view-customer.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id'));
})
```

In the php for view-customer.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = $id");
```

Should work.

Updated to take MassivePenguins (obvious lol) advice. The above will allow you to add a class to every link rather than having to create a call for each link individually.

Comment: That looks good but I'd give the links a common class as well, and perform the click binding on the class (or a generic,shared element like `$('#tableId tr.customerRow td').click(...`) rather than on a specific ID.

Comment: can i make the jquery so that when ever a link from that page is clicked like a.customer is clicked grab the id number and load the page? that way i dont have billions of jquery for each id thats clicked?

Comment: I just updated the answer to give how to do that, I should have done it to begin with tbh. Just wasn't thinking.

Comment: You guys rock I appreciate the help my mind just goes blank when I try to conceptualize this. Trying to make a quickbooks like web program for my company and to be able to click from a list of customers and view the details of the customer will help me greatly!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use function for it with the ajax:

```
function getcontent(var1){
 $.post("company/view-customer.php",{customerid:var1},function(data){
  $("#container").html(data);
 });
}
```

Then on every link:

```
<a href="" onclick="getcontent(".$row['customer_id'].");">Smith, John</a>
```

On view-customer.php, You can resolve the request as:

```
$id = $_POST["customerid"];
if(isset($id)){
 //ID is set and ready to use, Do other stuff here...
 //The Queries and anything else...
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = $id");
}
```

Using the function is more easier and you would have all your html data in that php file to pulled according to "id" used for ajax call. Ajax is the best option for your case here, and function makes it easier to use. CSS can be easily used on PHP file while .load() would make some padding and margin issues I think...